# Property does not exists on array element

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to return an array containing an initialized object and a number.

However I get the following error:

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'number | IObj'  Property 'foo'
>   does not exist on type 'number'

```
interface IObj {
    [k: string]: string
}

function test(fields: string[]){
    const foo: IObj = {}
    fields.forEach((x) => foo[x] = 'baz')
    return [foo, 1]   
}
const [foo, x] = test(['foo'])
foo.foo
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array literals by default typescript will infer an array, so when destructuring occurs each element will be `IObj | number`, the information that the first element is `IObj` and the second is a number will be lost.

In 3.4, recently released you can use `as const` to get the compiler to infer a readonly tuple (`return [foo, 1] as const`)

Or you can use an explicit type annotation to tell the compiler you want a tuple:

```
interface IObj {
    [k: string]: string
}

function test(fields: string[]) : [IObj, number]{
    const foo: IObj = {}
    fields.forEach((x) => foo[x] = 'baz')
    return [foo, 1]  
}
const [foo, x] = test(['foo'])
foo.foo
```

If you are going to use constants for the `fields` parameter, might I suggest a more type safe version of your code:

```
function test<K extends string>(fields: K[]) : [Record<K, string>, number]{
    const foo = {} as Record<K, string>
    fields.forEach((x) => foo[x] = 'baz')
    return [foo, 1]  
}
const [foo, x] = test(['foo'])
foo.foo //ok
foo.foo2 // err
```

Comment: Can the `Record` implementation still work if `fields` becomes an `IObj` ? (and the foreach is modified)

Comment: @Orelus Not sure I understand your question if `fields` is `string[]` (because it is used dynamically) `Record<K, string>` will basically be equivalent to `IObj`

Comment: Would something like `function test<K extends string>(fields: {[K: string]: string}) : [Record<K, string>, number] (...)` still work ? Or do i have to use Record like `test<K extends string>(fields: Record<K, string>)` ?